# Drupal website goes offline every 2 days for 15 minutes

Tags: cron

We provide hosting services (Dedicated Server) to a client whose website is based on drupal. This month, his website goes offline for 15 minutes every 2 days.

We already have monitoring tools (i.e pinguzo) showing that the server never went down. And the log files show nothing that is related to this issue. Also, there is no crontab entry executing every 2 days.

And we already checked the website many times at the same hour, but we never encountered the website while offline.

Nevertheless, the client still sends reports about this issue, and we do not know what could be the culprit.

Where should I look? Is there anything in drupal that can cause this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal can be configured to use a "poor man's cron" (exectuting jobs after a normal visitor's HTTP request). If you have access to the Drupal Admin UI, check `Admin > Reports > Recent log messages`, this is a core module helpful for debugging (it might be disabled though)

Comment: Thank you so much, I do not have access to the admin UI, but I will ask the client to send me the log messages.  Thanks again +1 ,

Comment: If you have access to the DB, you could look for a table called "watchdog", AFAIK this is the data source for the module

Comment: Thank you so much, I contacted the client and told asked him to check the reports, best !